# How to make a copied data, then insert back and update the values in one column, id will be auto-increment in the same table?

Tags: sql

Table Car

```
id  vin   car_name   mileage
1   1GH   HONDA      10,000
2   2LM   HONDA      10,000
3   3QW   HONDA      10,000
4   4RT   HONDA      10,000
5   5TY   HONDA      10,000
6   6UI   HONDA      10,000
7   7OP   HONDA      10,000
8   8BN   HONDA      10,000
9   9AS   HONDA      10,000
10  10GM  HONDA      10,000
```

Table Car

```
id  vin   car_name   mileage
1   1GH   HONDA      10,000
2   2LM   HONDA      10,000
3   3QW   HONDA      10,000
4   4RT   HONDA      10,000
5   5TY   HONDA      10,000
6   6UI   HONDA      10,000
7   7OP   HONDA      10,000
8   8BN   HONDA      10,000
9   9AS   HONDA      10,000
10  10GM  HONDA      10,000
1   1GH   HONDA      10,000
2   2LM   HONDA      10,000
3   3QW   HONDA      10,000
4   4RT   HONDA      10,000
5   5TY   HONDA      10,000
```

Copy the first 5 data, insert back and set new VIN values for copied data, id will be auto-increment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips. Also, [on homework.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` is an identity or auto increment column (or something comparable), you can use:

```
insert into car (vin, car_name, mileage)
select vin, car_name, mileage
from car 
where id between 1 and 5;
```

Not sure what "update the VIN" is supposed to be though.

Comment: I mean after you add copied data, then you set new vin value of those copied data.